# Set Statistics Time On retrieve total of elapsed time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can get the whole message coming out of SQL by hooking up to the InfoMessage event in c#. However, what would be the best way to calculate the total number of elapsed times from that output? As I'm executing the query on the stored procedure which runs multiple queries, but I'm only interested in how long the stored procedure took overall.

I've also tried calculating it through the variables, but I'm getting:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

Cheers.

Output:

> SQL Server parse and compile time:  CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0
>   ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 9 ms.
>   SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 8 ms.  SQL
>   Server parse and compile time:  CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
>
> SQL Server parse and compile time:  CPU time = 47 ms, elapsed time =
>   47 ms.  SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 31 ms, elapsed time =
>   62 ms.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 78 ms, elapsed time = 110 ms.
>   SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 7 ms.
>   SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

c#:

string query = String.Format("set statistics time on {0} set statistics time off", Query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use stop watch in your app, and measure the elapsed time,

```
//Import 
using System.Diagnostics;

//in your app
Stopwatch sw= new Stopwatch();
// initialize your connection and your sql command with stored procedure 
ws.Start();
YourSQLCommand.ExecuteNoneQuery()
ws.Stop();
Debug.Write("Time elapsed: {0}",
    ws.Elapsed);
```